# Lower bound on mixing time to lazy random walk on complete graphs

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk, mixing

Let $K_n$ be complete graph with $n$ vertices
and  $$d^{\infty }(t) := \max_{x,y\, \in V} \left|\frac{P^{t}(x,y)}{\pi(y)}-1\right|$$
and $$t^{\infty}_{\text{mix}} := \min \{t \geq 0 : d^{\infty }(t) \leq \frac{1}{2e} \}$$
we want show that for lazy random walk on complete  graph $K_n$, $t^{\infty}_{\text{mix}} \asymp \log n$.

the upper bound can be easliy get by directly plug into the eigenvalue bound
$$ t^{\infty}_{\text{mix}} \leq \frac{1}{\gamma_{\ast}} \log \frac{1}{\pi_{\min}} \tag 1$$ where $\gamma_{\ast}$
is the spectral gap.

but how to see the lower bound, what I have attempted is:

for any vertices $x \neq y$ , and let $\tau_y$ be the hitting time of $y$ and

\begin{align}
1-P^{t}(x,y ) & \geq   \text{Pr}(\tau_y >t)  \\
& = (1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})^t
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\max_{x,y\, \in V} \left|\frac{P^{t}(x,y)}{\pi(y)}-1\right| &\geq 1- \frac{P^{t}(x,y)}{\pi(y)} \\
& = 1- n\left(1- \left(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\right)^t\right)
\end{align}

and I think its don't make sense ...